# "integer argument expected got float"while running in raspberry pi.what can be the solution?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

```
def drawRedRectangleAroundPlate(imgOriginalScene, licPlate):

    p2fRectPoints = cv2.boxPoints(licPlate.rrLocationOfPlateInScene)            # get 4 vertices of rotated rect

    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), SCALAR_RED, 2)         # draw 4 red lines
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[2]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[2]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[3]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[3]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
    # end function
```

i am getting error when i run this in raspberry pi that  "integer argument expected got float"

Comment: Please edit your question so to include the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is each of your `p2fRectPoints` contains **float** instead of **int** type.
try this:

`def drawRedRectangleAroundPlate(imgOriginalScene, licPlate):
    # get 4 vertices of rotated rect
    p2fRectPoints = cv2.boxPoints(licPlate.rrLocationOfPlateInScene)
    # convert float arrays to int tuples for use with cv2.line()
    p0 = (int(p2fRectPoints[0][0]), int(p2fRectPoints[0][1]))
    p1 = (int(p2fRectPoints[1][0]), int(p2fRectPoints[1][1]))
    p2 = (int(p2fRectPoints[2][0]), int(p2fRectPoints[2][1]))
    p3 = (int(p2fRectPoints[3][0]), int(p2fRectPoints[3][1]))
    # draw 4 red lines
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, p0, p1, SCALAR_RED, 2)
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, p1, p2, SCALAR_RED, 2)
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, p2, p3, SCALAR_RED, 2)
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, p3, p0, SCALAR_RED, 2)`